# How to delete multiple open cache from service worker

Tags: javascript, caching, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I have been working on pwa project and i opened two cache 
one is static-cache and another one is dynamic-cache i am able to delete one cache at a time by using this code

```
self.addEventListener('activate', event => {
  console.log('Activating new service worker...');

  const cacheWhitelist = [staticCacheName];

  event.waitUntil(
    caches.keys().then(cacheNames => {
      return Promise.all(
        cacheNames.map(cacheName => {
          if (cacheWhitelist.indexOf(cacheName) === -1) {
            return caches.delete(cacheName);
          }
        })
      );
    })
  );
});
```

i want to delete both caches at same time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code looks already good. In my case, I use the following code to delete the SW caches:

```
if ('caches' in window) {
 caches.keys().then(cacheNames => {
   return Promise.all(
     cacheNames.filter(cacheName => {

      // You can have some custom logic here, if you want
     // to delete only some caches

      // If you return TRUE, the cache will be deleted
      }).map(cacheName => {
       return caches.delete(cacheName);
     })
   );
 })
}
```

The `caches.keys()` method returns the keys of the CacheStorage, an interface representing the storage for the Cache objects that can be accessed by the service worker.

I wrote an article about [service workers and caching strategies](https://dev.to/paco_ita/service-workers-and-caching-strategies-explained-step-3-m4f), if you want to deepen the topic.

Answer (score 1):

Not an expert but I think using filter like this will work.

```
 cacheNames.filter(cacheName => {
          if (cacheWhitelist.indexOf(cacheName) === -1) {
            return caches.delete(cacheName);
          }
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
self.addEventListener( "activate", event => {

  event.waitUntil(

    //wholesale purge of previous version caches
    caches.keys().then( cacheNames => {
      cacheNames.forEach( value => {

          caches.delete( value );

      } );

    } );

} );
```